# How to remove specific white space from image using ImageMagick

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

Currently, I have thousands of pictures where I want to get rid of white space around the object, but not inside the object. However, the white space is not constant. See pictures below.

Picture 1 :

[image]

Picture 2 :

[image]

Picture 3 :

[image]

Options like this don't work as they delete all white space in the images

```
convert image.png -fuzz 10% -transparent white output.png
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What do you mean by getting rid of the white space? If you mean make it transparent, then in ImageMagick 6, you can do a whole folder of images using the mogrify command as follows:

The process involves padding the image with 1 pixel border of white to ensure white is all around. Then doing a fuzzy flood fill. Then remove the extra one pixel all around. I have assumed that the background color is nearly white. Change the fuzz value as desired.

```
Create a new directory to hold the output (or backup your input directory)
Change directory to the one holding your input images

mogrify -path path_to/outdirectory -format png -bordercolor white -border 1 -fuzz 20% -fill none -draw "matte 0,0 floodfill" -shave 1x1 *.png
```

Here are the resulting images.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Of course you will have to download them to see that they are transparent.

Note that the images that I downloaded were JPG. So if your images are jpg and not png as in your command, then change *.png to *.jpg. Or just use * to change all formats.

See 
https://imagemagick.org/Usage/basics/#mogrify
https://imagemagick.org/Usage/draw/#matte

If using ImageMagick 7, change matte to alpha and change mogrify to magick mogrify.